# Can't uninstall package, trying to "overwrite" a file

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to uninstall the package 'gtk2-devel' (a CentOS package that I converted to DEB) using Ubuntu Software, but I get this error:

```
Unable to remove gtk2-devel:
Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/gtk-builder-
convert', which is also in package gtk2-devel 2.24.31-2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   The package clash is with a *debian* package, not a Ubuntu package (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libgtk2.0-dev).

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libgtk2.0-dev

Comment: @N0rbert Installing it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve your current situation run the commands below:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all gtk2-devel
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then install normally available development [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libgtk2.0-dev) for Gtk2+:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

---

Please do not invent RPM-based abstractions on top of normal mature and fully functional APT system. Next time please visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/ first to prevent such situations.

Stuff to read:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove.html.en
- `man apt` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man8/apt.8.html)
- `man dpkg` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)